# How to Automatically Checkout Git Branches on Remote Development Machine with PhpStorm

Tags: git, automation, phpstorm, remote-server

Bit of a curve ball here,

I use PhpStorm to handle my Git VCS processing including checkout. The issue I'm having is that my development machine is remote (EC2 instance) and everytime I checkout locally I have to reset the remote head and checkout remotely as well.

Is there a way that PhpStorm can automate this process?

My Remote Server is already setup correctly so that I can already perform "manual" file syncs on folders.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Deployment feature, that allows you to sync your local working directory with a remote one. It can be triggered automatically on a checkout.
But there is no way of executing remote git commands from the IDE, so it is not possible to checkout the same branch on the remote machine from the IDE.

Why do you need both machines be on the same branch though? You could do all changes on your machine, commit, then push to the remote and checkout that new changes when needed.

Comment: I already use the deployment feature to work on my current branch. which automatically syncs to the remote whenever almost instantaneously after any changes for 'live' development testing.

I need the remote machine as the system I'm working on has to be an EC2 instance due to the sheer size of the RAM / CPU / HDD requirements.

thanks for your help anyway :)